# "JVM creation failed" in netbeans 7.1

Tags: java, netbeans

I can launch the Netbeans IDE successfully. But, when I run the sample applications in the IDE, I always get the `JVM creation failed` message.

If I clean it, I can run it successfully, but only once. So, if I have to run an application, I have to rebuild it. Why?

I Googled for `JVM creation failed`, but only found the solution to fix the issue in launching the Netbeans itself.

Comment: Please share the solution to fix the issue in launching NetBeans itself.

Comment: Check this link : [How to solve the JVM creation failed error when starting Netbeans](http://massimilianomarini.com/node/6)

Answer (score 11):

You can find netbeans.conf under.

```
C:\Program Files\NetBeans\etc
```

This is the original conf row.

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"
```

Simply add this extra parameter to the above row.

```
-J-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Finally the row looks like.

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"
```

Now restart you NetBeans ...

Answer (score 0):

This error shows if you have any other IDE like Visual Studio opened. Just closing the that application  will solve that problem.